# Como mostrar solo hora con JasperReport?

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports

Tengo el problema que con JasperReport genero un reporte en donde manejo solo hora.

A la hora de generar el reporte me sale 1/01/70 y al lado la hora y yo no estoy manejando fecha.

¿Hay alguna forma de solo mostrar la hora?

[image: JasperReport]

Comment: ¿Quieres mostrar la fecha o la hora? ¿Con qué código estás trabajando para llenar el reporte? Indica también tu versión de Jasper (hay una nueva versión y otra que es obsoleta).

Comment: Y cómo estás generando el reporte?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola amigo una solución a tu problema es establecer la propiedad **Pattern** en tus campos hora de inicio y hora de fin con el valor **h.mm a** .De esta manera en el reporte solo mostrará la hora y los minutos en formato 12 horas.
Si lo que deseas es sólo la fecha establece la propiedad **Pattern** a  **dd/MM/yyyy**.

Otra forma sería modificando tu consulta sql y utlizar la funcion date_format() de la siguiente manera.
Para obtener sólo la **hora:**

```
select numero_horario, date_format(horario_inicio, '%h:%i %p') as hora_inicio, date_format(horario_fin,'%h:%i %p') as hora_fin 
from nombre_tabla
```

Para obtener sólo la **Fecha:**

```
select numero_horario, date_format(horario_inicio, '%d/%m/%Y') as fecha_inicio, date_format(horario_fin,'%d/%m/%Y') as fecha_fin 
from nombre_tabla
```

Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Hola amigo muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta, aplique la primera sentencia que me dijiste y lo logré corregir muchas gracias

Comment: Amigo si mi respuesta ha sido útil para solucionar tu problema, lo correcto es marcarla como usada. Para ello, tienes el icono del check ( ✓ ) situado a su izquierda.

Comment: gracias amigo ya lo hice